# Django override default functionalities

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

In django/django/contrib/auth/forms.py how to override the default method
and include the same in the users module ?

So my intention is that i want to change the username field length to 64 characters but this would not be correct to do this in django directories,because whenever new version is downloaded this file has to changed....

What exactly shoudl be changed to do this

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
 """
 Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
 username/password logins.
 """
 username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30)
 password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to override? What is the problem?

Comment: Do not forget to `ALTER` your user table schema from your DBMS. Because `usename` field of `auth_user` is 30 character long, and any string longer than 30 will cause a database level error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may be able to change it by sub-classing `AuthenticationForm` into e.g. `MyAuthenticationForm`:

```
class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=64)
```

This way, you would keep the validators from `AuthenticationForm`, but still let the username be 64 characters long.

Comment: Can this be done for the username field only?? If so i can overide the User() module username also to have 64 characters as well.

Comment: @Hulk: No, you basically can't change an existing model like that, at least not easily.

Answer (score 1):

@Deniz Dogan: You also have to convince login view to use the custom form:

```
login(request, authentication_form=MyAuthenticationForm)
```